# Open URL from Android device in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android

I'm using this code attached to a button:

```
public void openURL() {
     Application.OpenURL("https://www.google.com/"); }
```

How do I get this to open when running on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about running it on a specific platform. Unity will take care of it. Just run the game on android and on click of the button, the url will open.

Comment: I've been testing on Unity Remote 4 and it doesn't. If run the app on the Android properly I guess it will then?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the player setting from auto to required for internet access.  Also make sure you have http://www.  If you don't do both, then it will work on windows but not android.